# elasticbeanstalk describe-application-versions returning empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I have the following script that runs at the end of codebuild on AWS. It creates a new application version successfully and I want it to automatically update the environment to deploy the new application version. The command `describe-application-versions` returns empty, and the command `update-environment` starts an update, but it quickly fails with the error `InvalidParameterValue: Not a valid Base64 function`. I've double-checked that the environment variables are being set correctly, and I can call both commands fine from my own terminal. Is this maybe a credentials error? I would expect to see a permissions error if that were the case.

```
if [ -z $APPLICATION ];
then echo "No beanstalk application specified";
else aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name $APPLICATION --version-label $VER_LBL --source-bundle S3Bucket=$DEPLOYPATH,S3Key=builds/$APPLICATION/$VER_LBL --region $REGION;
    if [ -z $ENVIRONMENT ];
    then echo "No beanstalk environment specified";
    else 
        aws elasticbeanstalk describe-application-versions --application-name $APPLICATION --version-labels $VER_LBL --region $REGION
        aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name $APPLICATION --environment-name $ENVIRONMENT --version-label $VER_LBL --region $REGION; 
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I had the same issue.
I tried removing the config files as I thought there might be some issue with config files in `.ebextensions`.

But, it wasn't the case.

I was using the CodePipeline to deploy elasticbeanstalk (elasticbeanstalk was already deployed using CFN).
The error is somewhat bit deceiving in my case the issue was with the **IAM role**.

My **IAM** role for **CodePipeline** was missing the following bit:

```
          - Action:
              - iam:PassRole
            Resource: "*"
            Effect: Allow
            Condition:
              StringEqualsIfExists:
                iam:PassedToService:
                  - cloudformation.amazonaws.com
                  - elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com
                  - ec2.amazonaws.com
                  - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
```